# How to get an empty screen at Atom editor startup?

Tags: atom-editor

Currently when I start my Atom editor GUI (v1.60.0 x64) on Windows 10, I get this screen (warning: red circles added for explanation purpose):

[image]

I need to clic 4 times (on the red circles shown in the picute above) to obtain this clean screen:

[image]

Is there a way to obtain this screen directly at startup?

Comment: Please feel free to correct my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete solution but...
Uncheck the "Show Welcome Guide when opening Atom" checkbox and it will stop the "Welcome" and "Welcome Guide" tabs opening, also submit Telemetry Consent preferences and it will prevent the 3rd tab opening.
You will still need to hide the project pane but 1 click is better than 4 isn't it?